# Keeping track of files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-drive-realtime-api

I am having an issue with managing files. I have some content that will be updated on a daily basis and I want to parse the data from some of the files. But the problem I have having I don't want to touch the files I already did. How can I keep track of what was already done and where to start back the next time. Using nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files are on a local filesystem.
1. read the lastModifiedTime.
2. any time the lastModifiedTime is different from previous lastModifiedTime for the file update the lastModifiedTime and then parse and read the file

run steps 2 at regular interval. (60 seconds in the code)

```
var fs = require("fs");

var filePaths = ['file_name_1', 'file_name_2'];
var mtimes = {};
var reloadTimes = 60000;
var execFunction = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
        parseFile(filePaths[i], mtimes[filePaths[i]]);
    }
};
setInterval(execFunction, reloadTimes);
var parseFile = function(fileName, lastModifiedTime) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(err, fd) {
        if(lastModifiedTime == undefined || fd.mtime.getTime() !== lastModifiedTime.getTime()) {
            mtimes[fileName] = fd.mtime;
            // read the file and parse it
        }
    });    
};
execFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks much that should work. For some reason ur code isn't running

Comment: @Slygoth what is the error you are getting? I assume you replaced the file names with full path. The first time execution will not occur until reloadTimes milliseconds are over.

Comment: I just got a chance to run the code but its still reading the files over and over. Every 60 seconds it prints back the same file

Comment: yes that was because fd.mtime is a Date object. Need to use getTime() to compare with the lastModifiedTime. I have modified the code to use getTime it should work as expected now